# The method is undefined in fragment android spinner sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, spinner

I have a spinner. I want to load data from sqlite. I have try to load data with Activity class, it work but i want to load it in Fragment class and i got the method is undefined. There is any wrong ? What should i do ??

Sorry for my bad english..

This is Fragment class

```
public class InfoJadwal extends Fragment {
private DatabaseHandler dbhelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db = null;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        dbhelper = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    dbhelper.delAllData(db);
    dbhelper.generateData(db);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_jadwal, container,
                false);

    loadDataSpinner();

    return rootView;
}

private void loadDataSpinner() {
    Cursor wisataCursor;
    Spinner colourSpinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(
            R.id.spin_tujuan);
    wisataCursor = dbhelper.fetchAllWisata(db);

    startManagingCursor(wisataCursor);

    String[] from = new String[] { dbhelper.TUJUAN };

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvDBViewRow };

    SimpleCursorAdapter wisataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.db_view_row, wisataCursor, from, to);

    colourSpinner.setAdapter(wisataAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            db.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}
```

And this is class for DatabaseHandler.

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "medantrain";
public static final String TUJUAN = "tujuan";
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

// method createTable untuk membuat table WISATA
public void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS KOTA");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists KOTA (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + "TUJUAN TEXT);");
}

// method generateData untuk mengisikan data ke table Wisata.
public void generateData(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(TUJUAN, "Binjai");
    db.insert("KOTA", TUJUAN, cv);
    cv.put(TUJUAN, "Rantau Prapat");
    db.insert("KOTA", TUJUAN, cv);
    cv.put(TUJUAN, "Tebing Tinggi");
    db.insert("KOTA", TUJUAN, cv);
}

// method delAllAdata untuk menghapus data di table Wisata.
public void delAllData(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.delete("KOTA", null, null);
}

public Cursor fetchAllWisata(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    return db.query("KOTA", new String[] { KEY_ID, TUJUAN }, null, null,
            null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    createTable(db);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: which method is undefined?

Comment: can you share your log file/ error line number

Comment: this method is error startManagingCursor(wisataCursor);

and this SimpleCursorAdapter wisataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
    R.layout.db_view_row, wisataCursor, from, to);

  colourSpinner.setAdapter(wisataAdapter);
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
SimpleCursorAdapter wisataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.db_view_row, wisataCursor, from, to);
```

with

```
SimpleCursorAdapter wisataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.db_view_row, wisataCursor, from, to);
```

and replace

```
startManagingCursor(wisataCursor);
```

with

```
getActivity().startManagingCursor(wisataCursor);
```

but `startManagingCursor(Cursor)` in `Activity` is deprecated. see docs for more info http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startManagingCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29

*SimpleCursorAdapter* requires a Context reference but you are passing **this** which means a Fragment reference.

Comment: Thanks sir, but i get this method is error too..
startManagingCursor(wisataCursor);

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I forget this little code. I get the methods deprecated but it doesn't matter.